# Does OpenEBS support encryption at rest?

Tags: encryption, virtual-machine, openebs

My environment:
- K8S 1.9.x
- OpenEBS 0.6

I am using 5 vms for my worker nodes and many disks are attached to it. I want persistent storage for running kafka and mongodb app. I am looking for encryption at rest at storage level instead of encryption at container level. Does OpenEBS support encryption at rest?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution to providing encryption at rest, pointed out on the OpenEBS Slack Channel was to use LUKS in your host operating system to encrypt the volumes you want encrypted-at-rest. Example tutorial for CentOS: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/EncryptedFilesystem

Answer (score 0):

Currently OpenEBS does not support encryption at rest.